# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "703A "

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, netbeans-8.2, jtable

Mi proyecto consiste en listar todo el inventario almacenado en ciertos almacenes, luego, le hallo el 10% del total por cada almacén y lo muestro en otro listado. Y de ahí estoy tratando de eliminar toda una fila del JTable donde se muestran los resultados y que a la misma vez se me elimine de la tabla de la Base de Datos, mi código del botón Eliminar es el siguiente:

```
private void btn_EliminarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    int row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
    int opc = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Esta seguro que desea eliminar este registro?","Pregunta",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    if(opc == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
        try{
            Procedimientos.EliminarInventario(Integer.parseInt(jTable1.getValueAt(row, 0).toString()));
        }catch(SQLException e){
            
        }
    }
}
```

Mi procedimiento EliminarInventario es el siguiente:

```
public static void EliminarInventario(int a)throws SQLException{
    CallableStatement entrada = Conexion.getConexion().prepareCall("{call EliminarInventario(?)}");
    entrada.setInt(1, a);
    entrada.execute();
}
```

mi Procedimiento Eliminar Inventario en la base de datos es el siguiente:

```
GO
CREATE proc [dbo].[EliminarInventario](@Id_ProductoListado int)
as begin
delete from Producto_Listado where Id_ProductoListado=@Id_ProductoListado
end
```

y justo cuando le doy eliminar a una fila me sale el error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "703A  "
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at clases.Porcentaje.btn_EliminarActionPerformed(Porcentaje.java:631)
at clases.Porcentaje.access$000(Porcentaje.java:21)
at clases.Porcentaje$1.actionPerformed(Porcentaje.java:393)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

esto es lo que deseo que haga:
[image: imagen de eliminar]

IMPORTANTE: cabe destacar que el: For input string: "703A " cambia dependiendo del almacén seleccionado, en la imagen sale el 760A, y cuando lo ejecuté por primera vez estaba probando el almacén 703A

Modifique mi procedimiento almacenado así:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[EliminarInventario](@Id_ProductoListado int,     @Id_Almacen char(5))
as begin
delete from Producto_Listado where Id_ProductoListado=@Id_ProductoListado and Id_Almacen=@Id_Almacen
end
```

y la llamada del procedimiento en Java la modifique asi:

```
 public static void EliminarInventario(int a, String b)throws SQLException{
    CallableStatement entrada = Conexion.getConexion().prepareCall("{call EliminarInventario(?,?)}");
    entrada.setInt(b, a);
    entrada.execute();
}
```

y mi código del botón eliminar de la siguiente manera:

```
 private void btn_EliminarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    int row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
    
    int opc = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Esta seguro que desea eliminar este registro?","Pregunta",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    if(opc == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
        try{
            Procedimientos.EliminarInventario(Integer.parseInt(jTable1.getValueAt(row, 0).toString()),"");
        }catch(SQLException e){
            
        }
    }
}
```

Mi problema es que no se que parametros pasarle para que me reconozca el almacen que estoy seleccionando en ese momento. Me sigue saliendo el error de: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "703A "

Comment: Cuál es el campo Id_ProductoListado en la tabla?

Comment: @Jorgesys es un id autoincrementable (la llave primaria de esa tabla)

Answer (score 2):

El error sucede cuando tratas de convertir un valor no numérico a un numérico, por ejemplo, si tratas de convertir este valor a numérico obtendrás el error.

> "703A  "

Tienes varios detalles,

el primero es que deseas eliminar un producto, pero estás enviando al parecer el id del almacén.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema principal del error es que mandas a tu Stored Procedure el valor de "703A  ", cuando este solo acepta un valor de tipo int:

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[EliminarInventario](@Id_ProductoListado int)
```

El método `setIn()` debe usar los siguientes tipos de parametros:

```
.setInt(String parameterName, int x)
```

mientras que tu estás definiendo

```
.setInt(1, a);
```